# Проблемы с Wi-Fi при подключении IP камеры

Tags: сеть, ip, wifi

Имеется сеть из нескольких роутеров: 1 (ASUS RT-N12 VP), 2 (TP-Link TL-WR841N(RU) Ver9.2) и 3 (D-link DIR-615). Первый - главный, к нему подключен кабель от провайдера. К этому роутеру по WiFi и через LAN порты подключены несколько компьютеров, а также от одного из LAN портов проложен сетевой кабель до роутера 2. В роутер 2 этот кабель подключен в LAN порт, чтобы роутеры были в одной сети (иначе, при подключении второго роутера через WAN порт, он создает подсеть, что вызывает трудности при подключении камеры - об этом дальше). Третий роутер подключен ко второму по тому же пути LAN-LAN.

Итак, имеем такую сеть, и все устройства, подключенные к какому либо из роутеров имеют IP вида 192.168.1.х. Камера (IVM-2328-WiFi) по WiFi подключается ко второму роутеру. Для видеонаблюдения используется программа CMS (если бы во втором роутере кабель от первого был подключен в WAN порт, то у устройств, подключенных к роутеру 2, был бы IP вида 192.168.0.х, из-за чего на компьютерах, подключенных к 1 роутеру, не получалось обнаружить камеру).

Проблема заключается в том, что после запуска CMS и подключении к камере, начинает глючить WiFi у всех, кто подключен к какому либо роутеру. При этом состояние подключения на этих устройствах индицирует, что все в порядке. Однако все сервисы, будь то яндексдиск или мессенджеры теряют связь с интернетом. При попытке что-нибудь загуглить - на ввод запроса браузер предлагает популярные варианты поиска (это ведь говорит о том, что соединение все таки имеется?), однако при активации введенного запроса страница не загружается.

Comment: Пожалуйста постарайтесь структурировать текст. Читать один большой блок тяжело

Comment: *после запуска CMS и подключении к камере, начинает глючить WiFi у всех, кто подключен к какому либо роутеру.* То есть ни только камера, ни только CMS такого эффекта не вызывают - исключительно парой? Посмотрите загрузку сети от программы - может, она выжирает всё, что доступно... Попробуйте жёстко задать по роутерам 1, 6 и 11 каналы - продолжат глючить все WiFi или только на том же роутере?

Comment: *В роутер 2 этот кабель подключен в LAN порт, чтобы роутеры были в одной сети* Проверьте - возможно, роутер может функционировать в мостовом режиме. И вообще, укажите модели роутеров и камеры.

Comment: @Akina 1) Подключение к камере производилось только через CMS, а веб версия админки камеры очень убогая - там никаких настроек нет и изображения почему-то тоже (просто желтый экран), поэтому работа камеры проверялась только через CMS, а по отдельности проверить возможности не было. На текущий момент выяснилось то, что при отключенной от сети камеры ( стало быть и wifi соединение ее с роутером 2 разорвано), глюки с WiFi у пользователей продолжились. Решилось подключением кабеля от роутера 1 в WAN порт роутера 2 и перезагрузкой роутеров.

Comment: 2) Жестко задать каналы пока нет возможности, потому что боюсь, что эксперименты с сетью отрубят интернет у пользователей, что сейчас недопустимо. Попробую сделать это вечером.

3) Вроде бы роутер 2 в мостовом режиме функционировать может, но он находится на расстоянии около 100 метров от роутера 1, вряд ли возможно соединение. В любом случае, можно ли это как-то проверить?

Answer (score 0):

Удалось выявить причину проблем с интернет соединением пользователей. И дело не в камере вовсе. При подключении 2 и 3 роутеров в режиме коммутаторов, 1 роутер выдавал подключенным по WiFi устройствам в качестве IP адреса DNS сервера локальный IP третьего роутера. Выяснить, каким образом DIR-615 это делает, не удалось.

Пока что пришлось отказаться от использования 3 роутера, за неимением альтернативы. Когда появится - отпишусь, как всё работает.